# UIUserNotificationSettings types return wrong values

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

My case is as follow:

1. Install my app
2. Go to device's App Settings and turn off push notification for my app.
3. Remove My app
4. Re-install My app and get push notification setting programmatically as below:

   ```
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
           UIUserNotificationSettings *noticationSettings =     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
              if (!noticationSettings || (noticationSettings.types ==   UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
                return NO;
          }
       return YES;
   }
   ```

But, `notificationSettings.types` always returns `UIUserNotificationTypeNone` although in device's App Settings, notification setting is being on.
Can someone help me to get correct value of the notification setting in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You should check

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]
```

before call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

Here is the correct code:

```
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] == NO)
        return NO;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]){
        UIUserNotificationSettings *noticationSettings =     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
           if (!noticationSettings || (noticationSettings.types ==   UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
             return NO;
       }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that calling
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings]`
before calling 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:]` returns a wrong value.